# "Happens on" vs "Falls on" a particular date. What is the difference?

Tags: word-choice

> International women's day ***happens on*** or ***falls on*** March 8th.

Which should I use? Does *happen* or *fall* have a particular connotation?

Answer (score 3):

Either is acceptable in my opinion however I would tend toward **happens on** or **occurs on**, rather than falls on which would to me imply a date that is slightly more volatile  like Easter.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Idiomatically, you say "it falls on the 4th this year" when an event's date is variable. However, physical occurrences such as the solstice seem to sound better with *happens*. There appears to be a built-in idea as to which is the more fundamental reference, and that differs between *falls on* and *happens.*

Comment: This is simply wrong: International Women's Day is on March 8th every year. It does not fall on March 8th. It falls on some day of the week, yes. Also, happens ain't great. What happens when you boil water? He does not happen to know.  What's happening tonight? Answer: a lunar eclipse. Easter is not volatile,the stock market is. Easter is "a movable feast"; it falls on a different date (not day) every year.

Comment: Perhaps my usage of volatile was somewhat unjustified however the essence of what I said remains the same, falls on would imply a changing date, I know that volatile is more commonly used for stock markets however that isn't the only way you can use the word...

Comment: The question was about a commemorative day  on a ***set date***. Therefore, falls on is wrong. There is just no argument against that, I'm afraid.   You said: Either is acceptable. July 4th is July 4th. Independence Day does not fall on July 4th. It is on July 4th.

Answer (score 1):

One distinction is that "falls on" is more likely to be applied to a traditional annual event -- "Christmas falls on ...", "Thanksgiving falls on ...", etc.  "Happens on" is more commonly applied to a singular event:  "The company picnic happens on the 27th".

But the distinction is not very "sharp", and, in particular, one would be more apt to hear "The company picnic is on the 27th".

Comment: @Lambie - Christmas falls on a Tuesday this year.

Comment: Yep, great avoidance skills. I guess that's what it's all about...Game playing.

Answer (score -1):

Holidays or commemorative days are said to fall on a date as that comes from the Christian calendar. So, for example, Christmas Day is always the 25th day of December which can "fall on" any day of the week. Those were originally called "unmovable feasts".

So "fall on" has come to mean **can occur on any day of the week**.  International Women's Day ***is*** March 8 or is on March 8 and can indeed "fall" (occur on) on any day of the week. I would avoid "happen on some day  of the week" for a formal context (happen is more used as the result of something). "Fall on", therefore, refers to the day of the week, and not to a calendar day for International Women's Day.

In contrast, Thanksgiving (the U.S. holiday) does not fall on this or that day of the week. It is on the third Thursday of November and falls on a different calendar day every year.

So, for commemorative days with a set date, we say: X day is on [date: May 10th] and this year that falls on a Saturday. Or: X day is the second Sunday in June and this year that falls X date.

Fall on is used for randomness of a date or a day of the week. (I do not address the issue of leap  year here.) If the date or day are not random,fall on is not used. For example, Christmas falls on a Monday this year. I don't know what day it falls on next year.

[movable feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moveable_feast)

Comment: I did not address the leap year issue.  Movable feasts do fall on a different calendar day every year. Easter, for instance. My main point is that if a thing is on a specific calendar date (March 8th for IWD, we don't say that it falls on that date. It only falls on a day of the week.

Comment: The main point is that International Women's Day is on March 8th like all set commemorative events. There are a ton of them. And for those, the day of the week changes. Leap year makes no difference for that. March 8th is March 8th regardless. So, the leap year thing is just a red herring.

Comment: (1) You’re both wrong; Thanksgiving (in the US) is always the ***fourth*** Thursday in November.  (2) @Phil Sweet: What are you talking about? Thanksgiving is always on different dates on consecutive years.  (3) Lambie: [Hot Licks is right](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/466213/26083#comment1125372_466241): Christmas is on Tuesday (in 2018).

Comment: @Scott That's right, Thanksgiving is always on third Thursday in November. So it falls on a different  calendar ***date***, but not a different calendar ***day***.  And Christmas is always on the 25th of December, and therefore falls on a different calendar day every year. You only use fall for the calendar date or calendar date when either changes.If the date or day is pre-set, there is no falling.  One does not say: Christmas "falls" on December 25th.

Comment: Tsk tsk, downvoter. Lack of careful reading.